# How to cut this tag out in php?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I want cut out everything inside (tags included) from text, for ex:

```
[url=http://example.com]something[/url]
```

but with one condition, inside of `[url]` tag there would be `[img]` tag.
So final sentence to cut:

```
[url=http://example.com]anything[img]something[/url]
```

can anyone help? im bad with regular expressions, or there is easier way?

Comment: yawz. It's 1:30am over here & family guy is finishing, as is the beer, so time for bed. Can you figure out how to cut everything inside the tag? Can you figure out if it contains an IMG substring? Forget regexp, just KISS and use an 'if'. Life's to short, use an 'if' and move on.

Comment: You'd need a lot of regex gymnastics... `\\[url=[^\\]]*\\].*?\\[img\\].*?\\[/url\\]` would match everything on `[url=http://xxx.com]anythingsomething[/url][url=http://xxx.com]an[img]ythingsomething[/url]`.

Comment: just curious, what do you actually want to "cut out"?   what would you expect from each of those teams?

Comment: oh good question, because on our phpbb forum there are users registering to catch our users on phishing by name'ing for example [url=http://google.com]http://yahoo.com[/url] ... but in XXX forum there is sometimes legit [url= for ex: [url=http://biggerIMG.com/sss][img]http://smallerIMG.com/zzz[/img][/url]  .... So to correct my request, to cut out every [url= WITHOUT [img] tag inside of it, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$testCases = array(
    'foo bar baz [url=http://example.com]anything[img]something[/url] foo bar baz',
    'foo bar baz [url=http://example.com]anythingsomething[/url] foo bar baz',
    'FOO BAR BAZ [URL=HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM]ANYTHING[IMG]SOMETHING[/URL] FOO BAR BAZ',
    'FOO BAR BAZ [URL=HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM]ANYTHINGSOMETHING[/URL] FOO BAR BAZ',
);

foreach ($testCases as $testCase) {
    $results[] = preg_replace("{\[url(?!.*?\[img\].*?).*?\[/url\]}is", '', $testCase);
};

print_r($results);

?>
```

Comment: almost perfect :), it should remove when [img] is not inside, and now it remove when it is inside. Can this be easily fixed?

Comment: Sorry, guess I misread your comment above. I've modified the expression to pull those links without the IMG tag in them.

Answer (score 0):

I would try these lines of scripts

```
$subject = '[url=http]anything[imag]something[/url]';
$pattern = '@^\[url[^].]*\]{1}(.*)\[/url\]$@';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //anything[imag]something
```

Is the result what you want?

Comment: not exactly but will be usefull also, so first thing it wont remove (match) tags ([url ones) also. So it remove only what is inside tags, but it should remove whole thing if there is not [img] tag inside.